# In what scenarios do you use <section> tag of html 5, in place of <div>?

Tags: html

In what scenarios do you use `<section>` tag of html 5, in place of `<div>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information
>
> The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

[Source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-section-element).

[Further Reading](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/).

Also see [*When to use the `section` element*](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/).

Comment: I forgot but I read somewhere that if we use <section> then `<section>` should have `<header>` and `<footer>` inside. and I'm also confused between `article` and `section`

Answer (score 6):

From the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element)

> The section element represents a
>   generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this
>   context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.

[Do's and Dont's (s)](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/) for `< section >` tag